# Simple VBA macro in excel wont function as intended

Tags: excel, vba

My goal was to create a script that would identify a cell in column B (if it has the word "bug" in it) and then check the cell to the left of it, depending on what that cell contained "mili" "cent" or "nano" it would produce a value in column C on the same row. Then repeat this for each cell that contains "bug" in column B.

The table looks like this before running the macro:

[image]

I only started coding today so I've been using a macro created by ChatGPT, but it doesn't work, column C remains empty after running it.

This is the code provided by ChatGPT:

```
Sub Macro_test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim checkValue As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = "bug" Then
            checkValue = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
            If InStr(checkValue, "mili") > 0 Then  
                ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = "Success"
            ElseIf InStr(checkValue, "cent") > 0 Or InStr(checkValue, "nano") > 0 Then
                ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = "Success2"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I've tried multiple variations of this but none work

Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry if using AI code is taboo here

Comment: As long as you don't provide AI generated code as answer, it is fine. However, you should try to understand the code and, if it doesn't work, try to figure out why it is failing. There are several possible reasons, and as noone here has your data, it is hard to tell what is the real reason for failure. You should learn to use the VBA debugger and execute the code step by step (use F8) to see how it behaves and where it does something different than what you expect.

Comment: Try `If Trim(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) = "bug" Then`

Comment: I agree "bug" could be "bug " or possibly cells ae merged?or you are not on the correct sheet?

Comment: I, probably like many other on SO, don't look kindly on folks who say I generated this code on Chatgpt but it doesn't work.   Code posted on SO is supposed to be your own effort and you only post on SO when your encounter a problem you can't resolve so that you can gain learning from the experience.

Comment: FWIW, I recreated your data based on the screenshot and the posted code worked perfectly. This would suggest that cells in column B contain more than just the word "bug" and therefore CDP1802's comment seems most appropriate. Either that, or the data isn't on worksheet 'Sheet1'?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author is asking about source code, generated by artificial intelligence.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, again this is my first dip into coding and i will try to teach myself how to get familiar with the VBA debugger

Comment: All strings in column A start with `mili`, `cent`, or `nano`. All strings in column `B` are `bug`. So there is no case-sensitivity issue.  There is no error so a worksheet named `Sheet1` exists (but where?). `ThisWorkbook` is a reference to the workbook containing this code. If the code is in another workbook that workbook will be used. Specify the worksheet in the correct workbook with e.g. `Set ws = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")` (recommended) or use `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` (not recommended, but may sometimes be the only way).

Comment: So you thanks everybody for their help but don't say what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a complicated VBA solution. You can just do this with a formula in column C:

```
=IF(B:B="bug",IF(IFERROR(FIND("mili",A:A),0)>0,"Success",IF(OR(IFERROR(FIND("nano",A:A),0)>0,IFERROR(FIND("cent",A:A),0)>0),"Success2","-")),"-")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code generated by ChatGPT work perfectly on my computer. But you don't need to use VBA to obtain a result. See the comment of @Peh. If you need absolutely to use VBA to produce your data, for any reason, in my case I should prefer to put directly an Excel formula through the VBA code.

```
Sub Macro_test_otherSolution()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow 'the first row won't be included
        Cells(i, "D").Formula = "=Put here your formula" 
    Next i
End Sub
```

> 'Notice : it is not easy for a beginner with VBA to use double quotes
> inside of double quote to produce an Excel formula, but to help you
> to learn, you should find on this site many questions about this issue.
> Second notice : the formula proposed by @Peh doesn't work with the new
> Excel version and give the error #Spill! See : How to fix #SPILL! error in
> Excel or use a reference to the right and single row and copy your formula.